# Interactive video on HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to insert some interactive buttons on a video, responsive way. However I am not succeeding.

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yic3T.jpg)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XHyU.jpg)

This sample screens shows the video after finish.

The idea is to put the buttons over the icons of this menu, however I already tried several ways and no success. Im not being able to make the buttons positions on the exact position of the video.

And unfortunately it is not possible to add other elements within the video tag.

Here is my code, any suggestions?

**html:**

```
<body>

<video id="video" autoplay="true" width="100%" height="100%" class="video" onclick="onVideoClick()">
  <source id="video_src" src="videos/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
  // Listener quando o video terminal
  document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    onVideoFinish();
  });
</script>
```

**css:**

```
.video{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

Comment: You can position DOM elements as z-index overlays on top of the `<video>` element and attach any behavior you like to them. (If the visible parts of the "buttons" are baked into the video stream -- which if so, oops -- use transparent but clickable DOM elements instead of trying to match pixels exactly.)

Comment: Just a suggestion - Instead of trying to align buttons over the video, wouldn't it be easier to have one transparent button over the entire video, then determine the mouse position as to which button it pressed? That way the image always remains perfect.

Comment: The menu that you have over the video on finish is it an image?

Comment: Controls over video and making it responsive should be separate questions. Please keep posts to a single problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Dont forget to accept an answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have as a menu is an image you could use the [`<map>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) of html5 as [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) of w3schools , place onclick attributes on each area and do your coding.. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpp6v63k/) :
 **Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="javascript:" onclick = "alert('you clicked me the SUN')">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury"  href="javascript:" onclick = "alert('you clicked me the MERCUR')">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus"  href="javascript:" onclick = "alert('you clicked me the VENUS')">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** In order to use it for your answer i would propose the following steps:

The idea is to use the ratio of each element in relation with the image.

1)I would suggest to open the image of the menu with microsoft paint.

---> select the "view" tab and enable the "Rulers" and the "Status bar".

---> store the vertexes you need. You can get them simply by moving the cursor at the desirable point and the pixel coords will show at the bottom-left of the software

--->select the "home" tab and click at the "Resize" button.

--->check the "Pixels" radio button to view the width and the height of the original image.

2) Finally in order to express an arbitary point inside the image simple follow:(lets suppose that the coordinates of a point are 83,100 [width,height] and the image size is 800x500 [width x height])

```
//define the point coordinates
var vertex_X = 83;
var vertex_Y = 100;

//define the original image size
var imageWidth = 800;
var imageHeight = 500; 

//calculate the ratio of the point relative to the image
var vertexRatio_X = vertexCoords_X / imageWidth ;
var vertexRatio_Y = vertexCoords_Y / imageHeight;
```

after having the ratio you can use it like this:

```
function defineActiveAreas(){
    var videoWidth = document.getElementById("video").clientWidth;
    var videoHeight = document.getElementById("video").clientHeight;

    var pointNew_X = vertexRatio_X * videoWidth;
    var pointNew_Y = vertexRatio_Y * videoHeight;
}
```

You can do this for every vertex point. Also you can use this function and add it to when the window resizes with an event listener.

Comment: How to use this in a responsive way?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? Do you want to know how to select the areas you want of the image and add to them an interaction?

Comment: This coordinates on the example, they are fix values as the planet. My video have a width/height of 100%. How can i make this coordinates scaleable?

Comment: Also does the image of the menu have the width and height of the video?

Comment: No, the video have fullhd and the image of menu (the button) have something like 100x100. This static image of the sample its the video after finishes

Comment: So was the answer oriented to your problem? Please answer exactly what is missing so i can update and if what you want can form a different question do so and form a new one also..

Comment: Screen1 and screen2 both are screens of video (no image), what i want its to add some button over the bathroom icon, over the truck icon... but it has to be responsive. The buttons always must be on top of a specific part of the video...

Comment: got it..wait for it.. ;)